# Conditional formatting based on another sheet in Google sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

I googled for it and looked into many answers here, but it seems still not working for me.

I try to use this conditional formatting:

```
EXACT(A3,(INDIRECT("U_automatikus!A1:A")))
```

Here are the screenshots of my sheets.

Why it isn't doing anything?

[image: First sheet with the conditional formatting field]

[image: Second sheet with the values]

My aim is to mark those in the first sheet which are present in the second too.

Comment: Here is a copy of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PWNkx-8a4mZA3qrBC5bAUklmVcjzZmzkk1YSZAFoaMA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A1; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("U_automatikus!A$1:A"); A1))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmA2M0e36grOu1PYzMIJEkjZFhf9RO00VZgsk3RcadU/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Still no difference, I tried what you give exactly, and different variations of it, but nothing.

Comment: I have this working, for example
=MATCH(E1:E;"U";0)

Comment: Yes, added it as a comment to my question just above.

Comment: =EXACT(A1:A; D1:D) inside the same sheet, this also works now... I'm moving in the good direction I think

Comment: OKAY, this is working now for the first 12 rows but not the others (you can see in the shared copy)
=EXACT(A1:A; INDIRECT("U_automatikus!A1:A"))
why?